# How to add new daemon on Quagga Routing Suite?

Tags: routing, quagga

Some of the existing daemons are:

-zebra: Interface declaration and static routing

-bgpd: BGP routing protocol

-ospfd: OSPF routing protocol

-ospf6d: OSPF IPv6 routing protocol

-ripd: RIP v2 routing protocol

-ripngd: RIP Ipv6 routing protocol

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'a new daemon'?

Comment: I'm planning to create/modify a new daemon based on OSPF protocol but using different algorithm. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guide I found on the topic is [Zebra Hacking HOWTO](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/zhh.html). 
Other sources of information can be found [here](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/resources.html). You need to understand how 'threads' and timers work there.

I personally prefer look at source code of quagga. It seems not so readable for the first couple hours, but later they're getting OK.

Comment: Thanks Sir Pavel, I'm now looking into this. I'll be open for more further comments/suggestions regarding this topic. :)

Comment: I think better suggestion here is to try implement your own daemon. You have a lot of examples in the quagga source code :)